# Custom sql statement not sure what to call it or how to label - trying to group data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not really sure how to present this other than just showing sample data and asking if i can use a sql statement to get it into the format needed.

```
answer_id   question_id ticket_id   session_id  text    number  checkbox    date_entered
828382  1GEhvQ  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828383  1Nutt0  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    Email   NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828384  3YkmoS  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    5   NULL    11/10/2014
828385  45eaZC  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828386  4qjOfW  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828387  9TpFEU  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828388  A1Cssf  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828389  Aczsej  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828390  arMZhK  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828391  bcvPPz  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828392  BE6oKn  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    Not sure    NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828393  BVZDwH  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828394  BxZhMN  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828395  BZWjeD  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828396  C48KFu  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828397  DCmmBk  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    Blue    NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828398  DCmmBk  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    Red NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828399  DCmmBk  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    Black   NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828400  DCmmBk  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    Yellow  NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828401  eh13cu  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828402  hVu8OD  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828403  iIJyzK  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828404  khW2jJ  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828405  KwwpFn  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    5   NULL    11/10/2014
828406  LfMC6f  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828407  OxAik3  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828408  THx1GB  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    Request for follow up   NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828409  U8f1pj  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828410  U8VO3V  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828411  UkQTr1  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828412  UMaOg7  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    The actual cost of services NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828413  vla4wj  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    5   NULL    11/10/2014
828414  Wgu4G0  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828415  WnIin1  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    1 company   NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828416  Wzv4xh  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
828417  X2TmgT  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828418  xMWrYi  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    4   NULL    11/10/2014
828419  zV9AvA  01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    NULL    NULL    NULL    11/10/2014
```

I have a table called `results`. In `results` there are a bunch of records, for any given `ticket_id` and `session_id` (a `ticket_id` can have multiple `session_ids` which would signify separate sets of result data).

Above is an example on the complete set of records from one `ticket_id` and `session_id` combo. There are many questions, some questions have multiple records (signifying multiple answers to a question). An answer can be either text or number or checkbox true/false. One of those, never a combination.

Long story short, each ticket/session is a questionnaire response, these are the answers someone entered for one questionnaire. If it helps, i have another table which tells me what the questionnaire structure is, so has all of the question ids, type of question, type of allowed answer, etc. So i essentially know ahead of time what the records in results should look like for a given response, I just don't know what their answers will be. But i'm not sure that matters in getting what i need.

I basically need to export a `csv` with a record for each response, where the first column heading would be `ticket_id`, second `session_id`, third `1GEhvQ` (question_id #1), fourth `1Nutt0` (question_id #2), and so on. So it would look something like this:

```
ticket_id   session_id  1GEhvQ  1Nutt0  3YkmoS  45eaZC  4qjOfW  ….. date_entered
01eDo3x8    0j54feibccswuc45povved3d    4   Email   5   4   4   ….. 11/10/2014
```

And in the case where there are multiple answers for the same question, a comma separated list would result, or if necessary, multiple columns using the same heading - possibly with a numeric suffix or something, or not, doesn't really matter to me - with an answer in each.

I don't know if this is possible in one sql statement, or if i would need to utilize the other table somehow that has the structural makeup of the questionnaire? Can someone help give me some direction on whether this can be done? I can do it in an app but i was hoping to consolidate it all into a nice sql statement.

Comment: You should look at sqlfiddle.com. It will let you create a schema and add data. That way we can see what you are trying to do. The formatting of stuff in html makes this impossible to see what is going on.

Comment: it sounds like you want a group concat.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e82a3/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Dynamic SQL to covert all question values as header.

you can use `coalesce` to choose Non NULL value from `text` or `number` column

Also values are cast to varchar

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e82a3/7)

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)
SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT 
                                '],[' + t1.question_id
                        FROM    results AS t1
                        ORDER BY '],[' + t1.question_id
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @query = N'SELECT ticket_id, '+
@cols + ' , date_entered' +'
FROM
(SELECT t1.ticket_id , 
        question_id, 
        coalesce(cast(text as varchar(20)),cast(number as varchar(20))) as answer,
        date_entered
        FROM results t1
) p
PIVOT
(
MAX(answer)
FOR question_id IN
( '+
@cols +' )
) AS pvt
'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

EDIT:

As per OP Comment, if you know the questions in advance, you can do it with out dynamic sql

```
select ticket_id,
        max(case when question_id ='1GEhvQ' then 
           coalesce(cast(text as varchar(20)),cast(number as varchar(20)))
           else NULL end) as '1GEhvQ',
       max(date_entered) as date_entered
from results
group by ticket_id
```

Comment: Wow that's awesome. The only problem is, you end up with one of the 4 values for 'DCMMBK'. Is there a way to either combine them into the one field or put each one in it's own column?

Comment: By using the table that has structure info, i.e. what questions are in the questionnaire and what the answer types expected are, could you instead build a temporary table with that structure and fill it with the responses? Just wondering if that might be easier?

Comment: @sds, if you know all questions in advance, you can do it with case based aggregation and no need for dynamic SQL, but it will be big sql statement

Comment: Can you give me an example of part of it (one case?) and maybe I can figure out the rest? Maybe shorthand the logic of the rest? Just something so that I can understand the approach you're talking about and can try to work through it? Thanks.

Comment: i've created a statement that copies the questions into a temp table, and can iterate through the questions, can i use this to build the select statement above so that '1GEhvQ' is replaced by the current loop value of question_id from the temp table? Not sure if that makes sense, just wondering if I can still do this programmatically.

Comment: here is what i am trying based on your suggestion...does it look like i'm doing this right? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc61c/3

it works, i just don't know if it is right?

Comment: @sds, I think better to go with dynamic SQL approach as u have many questions, regarding the same dcmmbk, u can change that to dcmmbk_1, dcmmbk_2 in the table so I get all of thwm

Comment: i like the dynamic sql approach but i can't modify the question IDs. The other approach you suggested works, if i can just figure out how to concat the multiple answers for one question. I'm thinking, in the loop, should i do a quick lookup to see if there are multiple records for that ticket_id and question_id, then if so do something different to get all records for that question_id and combine? I'm just not sure how to deal with the multiple records for same question_id thing.

Comment: @sds, you don't have to change in original table, you can change it on temp table

Comment: any way you can pm me i don't have enough reputation and i was wondering about a couple things still maybe you can help?